# How to use Vuepress' custom prismjs syntax highlight theme within a VuePress project

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuepress, prismjs

I am currently writing documentation for a Vue Component library, utilizing VuePress.
Using VuePress' markdown I am able to display code with `<<< ./path/to/file.vue` for example.
This is nice because VuePress uses prism.js for displaying code and has a custom prism language for Vue syntax highlights (analyzing the html shows that a language-vue class is applied to the codeblock).

No I am using a Vue component that Build to dynamically display some code snippets based on component props.

Inside my component, I am using the following pre/code syntax.

```
<pre class="language-vue">
  <code ref="codesnippet">
    {{codeOutput}}
  </code>
</pre>
```

This displays a code box, but doesn't apply the language-vue CSS theme to it that VuePress uses in its code blocks. Is it possible to add this to my own component somehow, as prism.js is installed by VuePress.